# Joomla 2.5 save, save & close, save & new, cancel buttons do not work

Tags: joomla

When I try to create or edit an article, category, or module, I am unable to save or cancel the changes. When I click on the Admin buttons, nothing happens. The URL gets a "#" added to the end of it, and I get this error (examples from 2 different editors):

> ReferenceError: WFEditor is not defined
>   http://www.mysite.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit
>   Line 250
>
> ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
>   http://www.mysite.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=47
>   Line 247

I have Joomla 2.5.11, no other updates pending. JCE editor, TinyMCE, default, and RokPad all throw errors and don't do anything when I press the buttons. CodeMirror and None are the only editors that I can use to save the article. I have tried uninstalling JCE and reinstalling it, and no changes.

I don't remember the last time it was working, possibly January sometime, if not before then. I don't know if this has anything to do with settings in my php.ini file or not. That was the only thing that changed from the time it was working until now, but it should be back to the "default" settings.

I've tried reuploading the admin folder, but no change. I reuploaded all the Joomla files (except installation) this morning from the stable 2.5.11 package freshly downloaded from joomla.org today, and still having this problem. I've also tried purging cache from the updates manager as well as maintenance area. I've tried 2 different computers, Fire Fox, Chrome, and IE (this was the suggestion in one of the posts I found similar to this issue).

I have been searching for a resolution for months. Any topics I find that sound like my issue end up either not having a resolution, or it's something else that the person is having a problem with. I use both JCE and RokPad on dozens of other websites with no problems.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [JCE: ReferenceError: WFEditor is not defined](http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/index.php?f=623&t=165134&rb_v=viewtopic)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have extra plugins or modules published on all administrator pages? There could be an extra

Open your console (ctrl+shift+J) and you should be able to locate the error, once you do just try to locate the origin in your code, it's most likely not originating from Joomla core, rather from an extension / template.

Also bear in mind that plugins are active by default on both the frontend and the backend and very often they are not intended to run in the backend, nor tested in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

**I JUST FIXED IT!! :) : ) :)**

I just switched my hosting's PHP version from 5.4 to 5.3 and voila!  It functions as it should.  I hope this helps someone!  I'm not sure when/why I may be required to go back to 5.4 but for now this solves my problem.  Any idea as to why these two versions of PHP behave so differently?

Comment: There are *lots* of differences between 5.3 and later versions. The current version is 5.6; [5.3 is not even supported anymore and will not receive patches or security updates](http://php.net/eol.php). Downgrading to 5.3 is not a solution, just a temporary workaround at best.